# Google Appengine's Version of Heroku Piplines

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku, github

I used to work on Heroku a lot and *loved* their [pipeline feature](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines), that spins a new instance for every PR on github to test with.

We're using Google Appengine to serve a django app and are struggling to find an alternative for this live testing on the web.

Does anyone know what to use to do the same for Google Appengine? Is this something that needs to be built custom? Can't seem to find anything on google searches.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following two articles will help you.

Continious delivery with Bitbucket:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-bitbucket-app-engine

or you can use Gitlab (that's what I am doing)

https://medium.com/evenbit/an-easy-guide-to-automatically-deploy-your-google-app-engine-project-with-gitlab-ci-48cb84757125

Unfortunately Google Cloud does not offer any out of the box solution until now